# first app showing unread notification count from second app

Tags: xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

Notifications from a previous app are being shown on the other app.

I have re-installed the app on multiple devices.  If i send the notification out for one app then the unread notifications count of the other app are being displayed in the first app.
both apps are setup as different firebase projects.

Comment: You might wanna check your logic for updating badge count and also if you are using the correct bundle id for both apps

Comment: Hi, both apps are using different bundle IDs

Comment: Each app is independent and it won't affect each other when you send notifications.